# How do i dectect collisions between UIImageViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I tried to use `CGRectIntersectsRect`

```
- (void)placeLine{
    randomTop = arc4random()%300;
    randomTop = randomTop - 150;
    randomBot = randomTop + 300;

    line1.center = CGPointMake(randomTop, 000);
    line2.center = CGPointMake(randomBot, 000);

    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(ball.frame, line1.frame)){
        [self gameOver];
    }

    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(ball.frame, line2.frame)){
        [self gameOver];
    }
}

- (void)gameOver {
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
```

but for some reason it didnt work

Comment: sorry the code came out a little weird

Comment: You can try use `CGRectContainsPoint`, there is nothing wrong in your implementation though, might be the values are not matching..

Comment: Are you sure they both are in the same coordinate system? That is, they have the same superview? Their frames are depended on their superviews.